# ¿Cómo ejecutar una GitHub Action que está en una rama diferente a `master`?

Tags: github, github-actions

Tengo un repositorio en GitHub y deseo crear una GitHub Action para automatizar el proceso de creación y publicación de una imagen de Docker en el DockerHub.

Sé como hacer esto pero si creo la acción en una rama que no sea la `master` GitHub no la reconoce y no la ejecuta cuando se produce el evento configurado en esta (`push`).

Este es un problema conocido ([Workflow files only picked up from master?](https://github.community/t/workflow-files-only-picked-up-from-master/16129)) pero no he encontrado ningún truco para hacer que funcione.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene dado por el propio comportamiento de la plataforma GitHub Actions.

Según la documentación oficial cuando se dispara un evento se buscan los archivos de workflows en la carpeta `.github/workflows` correspondientes al commit y la referencia de Git (ej. `refs/heads/master` para la rama `master`) y para aquellos cuya definición `on:` incluya el evento disparado se ejecutará el workflow.

Esto quiere decir que si un evento ocurre en una rama en específico, entonces la definición del workflow tiene que estar en ese rama y en el commit específico vinculado al evento. De lo contrario no se ejecutará.

Es importante enfatizar en que, aunque el archivo con la definición del workflow esté en la rama vinculada al evento, siempre se ejecurá la versión del workflow correspondiente al commit también vinculado al evento. Por tanto, si en ese commit no existe dicho workflow TAMPOCO se ejecutará.

Para más información referirse a la documentación oficial: [About workflow events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#about-workflow-events)