# ¿Es necesario crear un fichero de workflow en una rama para que se dispare en GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, integración-continua

En mi repositorio, he especificado en la rama master un workflow de GitHub Actions con este encabezado:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - develop
    paths:
    - 'src/Solution/Cloud/**'
    
  workflow_dispatch:
```

Quiero que se dispare una acción como he especificado, una vez haga push en la rama develop y en la ruta `src/Solution/Cloud/`

¿Es necesario agregar este archivo en la rama "develop"? Si ya he especificado que rama deseada es develop en el archivo .yaml del workflow que se encuentra en master.

Comment: Hi. spanish is the official language for this site. please translate the question, if not it could be close.

Comment: Sí. [Esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383030/c%c3%b3mo-ejecutar-una-github-action-que-est%c3%a1-en-una-rama-diferente-a-master) puede ayudar.